# Task's threads launched by Spring Scheduler

Tags: multithreading, spring, hibernate, jpa

We are building a system that has a Data layer, Business Layer, Service Layer...
It also has a Scheduler that wake up every 5 seconds and look for Tasks in a DataBase Table, if there are Tasks to execute, a thread is launched to execute this Task.
The problem is that within the execution the task needs to read and update entities from the Data Layer, some of this entities has lazy loading and there's when it crashes with a LazyLoading exception, session closed before time.

```
    ERROR: org.springframework.scheduling.support.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler - Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.soft1.pack1.data.entity.InitialAlignment.initialAlignment, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:566)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:545)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:266)
    at com.soft1.pack1.data.entity.InitialAlignment.getDefenses(InitialAlignment.java:80)
    at com.soft1.pack1.data.entity.TaskMatch.run(TaskMatch.java:74)
    at com.soft1.pack1.negocio.TaskTaskExecutor.TaskTaskExecutorMethod(TaskTaskExecutor.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor40.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

We think our problem is more architecturally than technical.

**EDIT1:**
(from @radai comments)

1. InitialAlignment has a property called defenses, which iterates over
   a List property thats defined as lazy (annotated with something like
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY))
2. database access layer uses hibernate. this layer opens up an hibernate session, gets an entity, and closes the hibernate session after itself

Answer (score 2):

i cant be sure of this, but here's what i *think* happened to you:

1. you have some sort of database access layer that uses hibernate. this layer opens up a hibernate session, gets an entity, and closes the hibernate session after itself
2. your code calls into this layer to get an instance of `InitialAlignment`
3. `InitialAlignment` has a property called `defenses`, which iterates over some `List` property thats defined as lazy (annotated with something like `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`), which means its not fetched from the database until used. but lazy properties can only be fetched while the hibernate session that created the `InitialAlignment` instance is still alive.
4. your task (`TaskMatch`), which runs in a separate thread and has been given this entity, tries to access the lazy field, but the hibernate session that created the object has already closed, so hibernate cannot go back to the database and fetch your list, and thats the exception youre getting

the quickest solution would be to change the `fetch` property of your @OneToMany hibernate annotation on the list field.

Comment: you are right, that is the problem.
We would like to keep the lazy loading for performance reasons and not use EAGER fetch.
We already tried applying Transactional annotation but the scope of the session didn't reach the thread. Any other suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: add a special method in your data access layer - something like getAlignmentWithDefenses() that will return a "full" entity - either by uaing HQL ("select from Alignment join fetch defenses") or by getting an Alignment and calling getDefenses(), and then returning it. use this method when fetching objects for tasks. if thats your only use then you might as well go and make the fetch eager.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `@Transactional` to your scheduled method. This should create a session for current task execution.

Good luck!

Comment: ...but it wont be the same TX that fetched the entity